# Can I use Template String on object key in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, template-strings

Can I create an object passing the key value as template string?

```
const key = 'my-key', value = 'my-value'
const obj = {
  `${key}`: value 
}
```

Is there an alternative to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to use [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) syntax:

```
const key = 'my-key', value = 'my-value'
const obj = {
  [`${key}`]: value 
}
```

Note that if you just want to use a variable as key, you can write `[key]: value`.

Comment: Of course this can and should be simplified to `{ [ key ]: value }`